# USAMTS 2016-17 Round 2 problem set is out!

Tags: discussion, contests

Following up the "[It's that time of year again: USAMTS 2016-17 Round 1 problem set is out!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24989/its-that-time-of-year-again-usamts-2016-17-round-1-problem-set-is-out)" post here in "Mathematics Meta Stack Exchange" (posted by "Mathematics Stack Exchange" Moderator @[arjafi](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/8348/arjafi) on Sep 13, 2016), I noticed that the USAMTS ([United States of America Mathematical Talent Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_of_America_Mathematical_Talent_Search)) has updated their Problems page of their web site - "**Problems for Year 28 (2016-2017)**" page available at http://www.usamts.org/Problems/U_Problems.php - by:

- Adding the "**Solutions**" to the **Round 1** problem set - available at http://www.usamts.org/Solutions/Solutions_28_1.pdf
- Adding the "**Problems**" of the **Round 2** problem set - available at http://www.usamts.org/Tests/Problems_28_2.pdf

So, my guess is that now (I'm posting this on Oct 23, 2016):

- The "ban" concerning "Round 1" questions, here on "Math Stack Exchange", may now be lifted (given that the Solutions for that Round problems are now officially available).
- There should be a "ban" on "Round 2" questions, and that @arjafi's recommendations are again applicable (but this time concerning "Round 2" Questions, instead of "Round 1" Questions) namely the following recommendations: all users should be on the lookout for these problems, and flag them for moderator attention when users see them, so that Moderators can lock those questions according to the [policy on ongoing contest problems](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16774/8348). Participants can submit solutions until 28 November 2016, and so the moderators will keep these questions locked until at least a UTC-day or two later.

Am I right?